# Internet explorer 11 and jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, internet-explorer-11

I use jQuery and jQuery UI.

This code works **perfectly** :

```
$('#mydiv').dialog();
```

But this one **doesn't work** (**only in IE 11**) :

```
    $('#bouton').click(function () {

        $('#mydiv').dialog();       
    });
```

I get the message "Object or method "dialog" does not exist"...

It seems that the dialog () method cannot be accessed into the jQuery click() function. It is really strange...

As a alreday said, this problem seems to occur only in IE 11 (it is OK in IE 10!).

Thank you very very much for you help, I'me trying to solve it for hours...

Comment: Which version of jQuery?  Which version of jQueryUI?

Comment: May we see your HTML?

Comment: Can you provide more context? And your actual HTML markup or a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Might work if you use ?

```
$('#bouton').click(function () {
    $('#mydiv').modal('show');      
});
```